# Nested types in Swift - what is the good practice?

Tags: swift, swiftlint

I have a `swiftlint` warning that bothers me.

`warning: Nesting Violation: Types should be nested at most 1 level deep (nesting)`

However, the nesting of structs is an established programming technique, and [quite](http://www.codingexplorer.com/using-nested-type-swift/) a few [people advocate](http://www.jessesquires.com/swift-namespaced-constants/) it.

Edit:
Indeed @vadian points out the [Swift language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/NestedTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH23-ID242)'s rule:*To nest a type within another type, write its definition within the outer braces of the type it supports. **Types can be nested to as many levels as are required**.*

I am aware it [clashes](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27204) with the use of [generics](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12298), and that Xcode may become unbearably [slow](http://openradar.appspot.com/18489684). It actually was (through [measuring](http://irace.me/swift-profiling) the slowest compilation spots) the reason why I started looking at this nesting rule.

*What is the reason for the lint rule, and what is the good practice in that respect? Please point out the technical reasons, rather than purely opinion-based advice.*

Microsoft actually has a [page about nested types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229027(v=vs.100).aspx), and when they are appropriate. While it is not targeted at Swift, it does have some interesting trans-language thoughtbits.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `swiftlint` but actually Apple says in the Swift Language Guide: [To nest a type within another type, write its definition within the outer braces of the type it supports. **Types can be nested to as many levels as are required.**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/NestedTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH23-ID242)

Comment: `String.CharacterView.Index` is used by the Swift standard library.

Comment: @MartinR true enough, which is exactly why I've stated it's an "established technique", and why I ask the question "what is the reason for this linting rule". Surely people don't make linting rules without good reason?

Comment: I don't know of a technical reason. It seems more like a "best practice" (and opinion-based) rule to me, like "a function should not be longer than nn lines" or "indenting should use 4 spaces".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After much searching, all I've found is [@jpsim's remark](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/issues/1151) that "the idea behind the nesting rule is to avoid complex interfaces".

Therefore, apart from the compiler issues outlined in my question, which will eventually subside, there seems to *not* be any technical reason for this rule.