# Nesting violation. Types should be nested at most 1 level deep

Tags: ios, swift, swiftlint

```
struct Email {
    struct Constraints {
        static let top = 20.asConstraint()
    }

    static let placeholder = "login_email"
}
```

[image]

How to fix that issue?

Comment: is it swift lint warning? it does not look like xcode warning but lint bug

Comment: This seems to be produced by [`swiftlint`](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/blob/master/Rules.md#nesting). So, just edit the rules file

Comment: Yes, this is a swift lint warning;) but I need to produce better code, not to exclude the rule from lint;)

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Oh I see. Truth is, that it's not very clear from your question. Can you please give us a short definition of 'better code' in this context?

Comment: not all of us use swiftlint, why not let us know where did you get a warning from?

Comment: What version of swiftlint are you using? What version of Swift? I know there was a bug where the `enum` cases were treated as type declaration (so e.g. an `enum` within  a `struct` produced this warning), but this has been fixed. See [issue 190](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/issues/190). In you example above, it seems as if, similarly, the static property `top` is treated as a type declaration, breaking swiftlint:s nesting depth limit of 1.

Comment: @Alladinian yes, what to do make this warning disappeared?

Comment: Also note that this particular swiftlint warning has been discussed [priorly at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996275/nested-types-in-swift-what-is-the-good-practice), noting that there seem to be no technical reason for it, and that e.g.the Swift standard libs use deeply nested types itselfs, an that that Swift API guidelines does not recommend against such practice. So you might simply want to disable this swiftlint rule (`// swiftlint:disable nesting`).

Comment: @dfri I think you are right. I am convenienced;)

Answer (score 15):

This particular rule of [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint), [`nesting`](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/blob/master/Rules.md#nesting), has priorly been discussed in the following Q&A:

- [Nested types in Swift - what is the good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996275/nested-types-in-swift-what-is-the-good-practice)

With somewhat of an consensus that this rule is not based on a technical reason, but rather seem to be an opinion-based "best practice" rule, noticeably not one followed e.g. by the Swift standard libs (which use nested type frequently). Moreover, the Swift language guide, specifically the [Nested Types Section](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/NestedTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH23-ID242), contains no warning for/recommendation against nesting type deeper than depth 1.

> ... Types can be nested to as many levels as are required.

One motivation for this (opinion-based rule) can be found in [SwiftLint issue 1450](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/issues/1450):

> *jpsim*:
>
> The nesting rule exists for two reasons:
>
> - to avoid overly-nested types in an API
> - to avoid overly-indented statements (aka pyramid of doom)
>
> ...

Based on the above, unless you find your code turning into unreadable pyramid of doom spaghetti (which I don't believe to be the case in your example), you could simply considering disabling [the `nesting` rule](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/blob/master/Rules.md#nesting):

```
// swiftlint:disable nesting
```

Answer (score 10):

try adding this rule in your `.swiftlint.yml`

```yaml
nesting:
  type_level:
    warning: 3 --> this means the warning appears if you nest 3 level deep instead of 1
    error: 6
  function_level:
    warning: 5
    error: 10
```

Reference: https://realm.github.io/SwiftLint/nesting.html

Answer (score 6):

You can create another struct:

```
struct Email {
    let constraints = EmailConstraints()
    let placeholder = "login_email"
}

struct EmailConstraints {
    let top = 20.asConstraint()
}
```

As you mentioned later on in comments, since this is only a linter error, you can disable this rule in *swiftlint.yml* file.

Comment: It is *not* a problem of the Swift version, Swift 2 (and probably 1.2) supports nested structs.

Comment: @MartinR You're right. Since Swift 3.1 you can use nested types inside generics.

Answer (score 0):

A universal cure for idiotic suggestions from swiftlint is (drums)

```
// swiftlint:disable all
```

at the top of the source file. But you imho should take step back and ask a more basic question (which is increasingly more difficult to answer in this job market). Do you want to work for an employer
where this nincompoopous tool (or any other linter) is utilized?